# Add standard routes with methods on the router

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

In Backbone.Marionette documentation some statement puzzled me:

> You can also add standard routes to an AppRouter with methods on the router.

(https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.approuter.md)

How it might look like in reality?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a route on the AppRouter and define the method to handle it in either the router or controller.

```
MyRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
  // "someMethod" must exist at controller.someMethod
  appRoutes: {
    "some/route": "someMethod"
    "yet/anotherRoute": "routerMethod" // app router route
  },

  /* standard routes can be mixed with appRoutes/Controllers above */
  routes : {
    "some/otherRoute" : "someOtherMethod"
  },
  // method on the router
  routerMethod: function() { 
  // ...
  },
  someOtherMethod : function(){
    // do something here.
  }
});
```